# Android studio - Gradle sync is failed

Tags: android, gradle

[image]
I already installed Android Studio and i tried to work on design part, but that gradle is not sync with the project. I have took screenshot of my error. Try to look it out and i need appropriate answer and solution.

Comment: Do you have a working internet connection while syncing gradle ?

Comment: yeah i have internet access while using it.

Comment: Paste the error log in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have remove the dependencies

```
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
```

So you should delete the AndroidTestFile too which have classes depended on this dependencies

Comment: Okay I will try it. Thank You

Comment: Yes check it and Inform that did it solved your problem